# restructuring a table in python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two tables they are data frames objects (pandas) as seen below:

```
   Table 1            Table 2
 col1 col2 col3     col1  col2  col3 
   A  |a1|   1        A   |b1|  2
      |a2|   3            |b2|  1
      |a3|   2        B   |b1|  1
   B  |a1|   1            |b2|  2
      |a2|   5        C   |b1|  2
   C  |a1|   0            |b2|  0       
      |a2|   3
      |a3|   4
```

I want to create something like this:

```
  a1  a2  a3  b1  b2
A  1   3   2   2   1
B  1   5   0   1   2
C  0   3   4   2   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`pandas.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col3': [1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 0, 3, 4], 
                    'col2': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a1', 'a2', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3'], 
                    'col1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']})
df1 = df1.set_index(['col1','col2'])
print (df1)
           col3
col1 col2      
A    a1       1
     a2       3
     a3       2
B    a1       1
     a2       5
C    a1       0
     a2       3
     a3       4

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col3': [2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0], 
                    'col2': ['b1', 'b2', 'b1', 'b2', 'b1', 'b2'], 
                    'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C']})
df2 = df2.set_index(['col1','col2'])
print (df2)
           col3
col1 col2      
A    b1       2
     b2       1
B    b1       1
     b2       2
C    b1       2
     b2       0
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])['col3'].unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
col2   a1 a2 a3 b1 b2
col1                 
A       1  3  2  2  1
B       1  5  0  1  2
C       0  3  4  2  0
```

Last if need remove columns, index names add [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])['col3'] \
       .unstack(fill_value=0) \
       .rename_axis(None) \
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
   a1  a2  a3  b1  b2
A   1   3   2   2   1
B   1   5   0   1   2
C   0   3   4   2   0
```